# Why does Bootstrap modal not render dynamically added content?

Tags: modal-dialog

I am trying to add content to the modal-body dynamically, but finding that html tags are not rendered, instead they are displayed as raw text.  Here is what I am doing: I have html table of users with one column showing a button that when clicked passes a semicolon delimited list of groups to a script to replace the semi-colons with html break character 
:

```
<button id="showGroupsModal_2321" title="Show Groups" onclick="showGroupsModal(2321,'Group 1;    Group 2; Group 3; Group 4')" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#GroupsModal" type="button">Show Groups</button>
```

The function goes like this:
e.g.: currArray = "2321, Group 1; Group 2; Group 3; Group 4"

```
const showGroupsModal = (userName, Id, currArray) => {
    let groups = currArray.split(',')[1];
    let groupsWithBreaks = groups.replace(/;/g, '<br>');

    let userGroupNames = document.createTextNode(groupsWithBreaks);
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.appendChild(userGroupNames);

    document.querySelector('#modal-body').append(newDiv);
}
```

The modal renders and displays the group list like this:

```
<div class="modal-body" class="modal-body">
    <div>Group 1<br> Group 2<br> Group 3<br> Group 4</div>
</div>

______________________________________________________

Group 1<br /> Group 2<br /> Group 3<br /> Group 4
______________________________________________________
```

Because some of the group names are very long, the goal is to place each name on new line. I haven't seen anything in the documentation prohibiting dynamic html content, and there are postings showing loading content from a external script and sites, but not in the way I am doing?  Is there a different/better way to achieve this using the array data?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the formatting  problem by splitting the semicolon delimited list [1] into another  array,  then iterating over that array to create listitem nodes in a for loop and append each node to a  element.

```
const showGroupsModal = (userName, Id, currArray) => {
    let groups = currArray.split(',')[1];
    let groupArr = groups.split(';');
    let ulTag = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < groupArr.length; i++) 
    {
        let liTag = document.createElement('li');
        let liText = document.createTextNode(groupArr[i]);
        liTag.appendChild(liText);
        ulTag.appendChild(liTag);
    }

    document.querySelector('#modal-body').append(ulTag);
}
```